# how to solve maximal sum problem using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to find the maximal square consisting of only 1's in a grid containing 0's and 1's.
link to the problem-[text](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximal-square/description/)

i tried solving it using recursion but the answer is always 0

this is what i tried..

```
public static int helper(char[][] matrix, int m, int n) {
    if (m < 0 || n < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    if (matrix[m][n] == '0') {
        return 0;
    }

    int left = helper(matrix, m - 1, n);
    int up = helper(matrix, m, n - 1);
    int diag = helper(matrix, m - 1, n - 1);
    
    return 1 + Math.min(left, Math.min(up, diag));
}
```

Comment: So what happens if you have a large matrix and the bottom-right value is '0'? This should give a hint...

Comment: There is a small error in the question's title:  It's maximum *square*, not maximum *sum*.

Comment: You didn't show the code that starts the process. Please show the code from the `solution` method. It might be `public int maximalSquare(char[][] matrix) { return helper (matrix, matrix.length, matrix[0].length);`, but we shouldn't have to guess that it is.

Comment: You should get some insights if you run the code in a debugger. Set a breakpoint early, and then run the code one-step-at-a-time.